# Turning indexed accesses to pointer accesses

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Say I have a function `int access_p_i(uintptr_t i)` that accesses
`p[i]` where `char *p;` is a global variable.

```
char *p;
int access_p_i(uintptr_t i)
{
    return printf("p[%lx]=%c\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

The intended usage is as follows:

```
char buf[] = "abcde";
p = buf; /*set p once*/
access_p_i(3); //prints p[3]=d
access_p_i(2); //prints p[2]=c
```

Say I want to hijack it (without modifying the function) to take absolute pointers:

```
memset(&p,0,sizeof(char*)); /*set p once*/
access_p_i((uintptr_t)"d");
access_p_i((uintptr_t)"c");
```

Would this be portable and legal C?

Comment: @2501 What I really want to do is have that pointer in a struct, and have one function that manipulates that struct, primarily via indices, but sometimes, I'd like to switch it to raw pointers, and I'm wondering if I could do with just one function for both cases (I use indices because I store them, and I don't have to rewrite them if the base rellocates).

Comment: @2501 It cannot possibly work, yet it does work perfectly well ([demo](http://ideone.com/b10yMu)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That doesn't mean it isn't undefined behavior. The standard defines behavior, not an output of a compiler. Gcc is just very forgiving here.

Comment: @2501 You're probably right. It will only work if `(char*)an_unintptr_uint == (char*)(uintptr_t)0 + an_unintptr_uint`
and the standard probably offers no such guarantee. It'll probably work on most (all?) platforms, though (works with all my C compilers (gcc, clang, tcc)).

Comment: @PSkocik potrzebie has the answer. It isn't even implementation-defined, it is straight undefined. See my comments on it.

Comment: It's not portable as written because there is no guarantee that you can format `uintptr_t` with `%lx` — there are environments where that won't work (Win64, for example).  If you fixed that, it works.  Hardly good practice, though; it should be enough to make your skin creep.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it's OK. From ANSI/ISO 9899-1990, about adding or subtracting an integer to/from a pointer:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Unless both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or the pointer operand points one past the last element of an array object and the result points to an element of the same array object, the behavior is undelined if the result is used as an operand of the unary * operator.

Comment: However, in OP's case both the operand and the result do point to elements of the same array object (in his case, it's an array of characters inside string literals).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight *Unless both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object,* The pointer and the result don't *both* point to the *same* object. Pointer points to no object as it is a NULL pointer, and the result does point to an object.

Comment: In other words, the requirement for pointer arithmetic is that both pointer and the result point to the same object, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The math behind the indexed access will continue working, because indexing `a[b]` is another way of writing `*(a+b)` or its equivalent `*(b+a)`, leading to odd equivalency between normal `p[i]` and inverted `i[p]`.

However, this code would not be portable, because there is no guarantee in the standard that `char*` can be converted to `size_t` without a loss.

> What if I replaced all `size_t` with `uintptr_t`

Assuming that `uintptr_t` is available on your target system, you would need to change `memset(&p,0,sizeof(char*))` call with `p = (char*)(uintptr_t)0` assignment. It shouldn't matter on most systems, though.

Answer (score 0):

ISO/IEC 9899:1999 7.18.1.4 says that `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are optional, and in 7.18/4:

> An implementation shall provide those types describe as "required", but need not provide any of the others (described as "optional").